# Need to upgrade svn on centos

Tags: centos, subversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to upgrade svn on centos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6506/need-to-upgrade-svn-on-centos)

I have an error when I run `svn up`

> svn this client is too old to work with working copy...please get a newer subversion client

This is on centos. I need to update svn. How do I do this?

```
[user@somewhere cms]$ sudo yum install
subversion Loaded plugins:
fastestmirror Loading mirror speeds
from cached hostfile * addons:
mirror.chpc.utah.edu * base:
mirrors.usc.edu * extras:
mirror.chpc.utah.edu * updates:
centos.mirror.facebook.net Setting up
Install Process Package
subversion-1.4.2-4.el5_3.1.i386
already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

`yum update` does the same thing. Additionally, only one directory is supposedly affected, but deleting this from the repository doesn't fix the issue.