# Need to upgrade svn on centos

Tags: centos, subversion

I have an error when I run `svn up`

> svn this client is too old to work with working copy...please get a newer subversion client

This is on centos. I need to update svn. How do I do this?

```
[user@somewhere cms]$ sudo yum install
subversion Loaded plugins:
fastestmirror Loading mirror speeds
from cached hostfile * addons:
mirror.chpc.utah.edu * base:
mirrors.usc.edu * extras:
mirror.chpc.utah.edu * updates:
centos.mirror.facebook.net Setting up
Install Process Package
subversion-1.4.2-4.el5_3.1.i386
already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

`yum update` does the same thing. Additionally, only one directory is supposedly affected, but deleting this from the repository doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RHEL 5.6 has Subversion 1.6 in it (from 1.4 in 5.5), so as soon as CentOS has released the RHEL5.6 package it'll just automatically upgrade.  If you can't wait, then you can rebuild your own package from [Red Hat's source package](http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Client/en/os/SRPMS/subversion-1.6.11-7.el5.src.rpm).

Comment: [rgriffin@lnxcmsdev ~]$ sudo rpm -i subversion-1.6.11-7.el5.src.rpm 
[sudo] password for user: 
warning: subversion-1.6.11-7.el5.src.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 37017186
error: cannot create %sourcedir /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES

Comment: Sorry, when I suggested you use the Source RPM, that meant you'd have to build it from the source.  This is what the CentOS maintainers will eventually do.  If you would like to build your own package, follow the instructions in the CentOS SetupRpmBuildEnvironment wiki: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetupRpmBuildEnvironment  (or, just wait until they release CentOS 5.6, which should be soon).

Comment: ... and here are the instructions to actually building the package: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM

Answer (score 1):

Try to search in http://rpm.pbone.net for "subversion-1.5" if that's what you need or just change it to "subversion-1.6" if in case you need that version limiting your search to "Centos 5" or "RHEL 5" and download the rpm that corresponds to your machine.

Install it via rpm as follows:

> rpm -i subversion-package-name-here.rpm

If it says it conflicts with your existing subversion, check for the name of your existing subversion:

> rpm -qa| grep subversion

and use the result for uninstalling the old package:

> rpm -e subversion-old-package.bhabha

Then go back to installing the rpm as I detailed above.

Answer (score 0):

http://the.earth.li/pub/subversion/summersoft.fay.ar.us/pub/subversion/latest/ also has the latest RPMs (no rebuilding needed) for CentOS 4 and 5 which is what I've always used. [via](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#redhat)

Comment: mmckinst, It seems that the contents of http://the.earth.li/pub/subversion/summersoft.fay.ar.us/pub/subversion/latest/ cannot be seen from my end. Maybe the permission is restricted? Coz that would have been a better alternative than searching through rpm.pbone.net as I've suggested

Answer (score -4):

Probably `apt` or something along those lines could update it. I'm not familiar with the package manager on CentOS.

Comment: [user@somewhere cms]$ sudo yum install subversion
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.chpc.utah.edu
 * base: mirrors.usc.edu
 * extras: mirror.chpc.utah.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.facebook.net
Setting up Install Process
Package subversion-1.4.2-4.el5_3.1.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do