# How do I enable a new repository in CentOS?

Tags: centos, subversion, upgrade

I need to upgrade my version of subversion however, simply running `yum update subversion` tells me:

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Loading
>   mirror speeds from cached hostfile  *
>   addons: mirror.nic.uoregon.edu  *
>   base: mirror.ubiquityservers.com  *
>   extras: centos.promopeddler.com  *
>   updates: mirror.chpc.utah.edu Setting
>   up Update Process No Packages marked
>   for Update

So, I need to know how I can find a repository for subversion-1.6 and the steps involved to impliment this repository on my machine.

I see this rpm here: http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Client/en/os/SRPMS/subversion-1.6.11-7.el5.src.rpm but I don't know that this really helps.

Thank you very much!

Comment: as for the Subversion SRPM, did you follow the instructions described here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6506/need-to-upgrade-svn-on-centos/6510#6510

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to install that specific package you can just do

> wget http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Client/en/os/SRPMS/subversion-1.6.11-7.el5.src.rpm
>
> rpmbuild --rebuild subversion-1.6.11-7.el5.src.rpm

However the rpmforge repo has 1.6.6 in it, so you can enable that repo if you wish.

> rpm -ivh http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
>
> yum update subversion

Assuming of course that x86_64 is your arch, if not you can change that to `i386`

Comment: One last question. How do I determine which architecture the system is? Either 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: I ran uname -a and found out that it is i386 however, the response from the command: 'sudo yum install --nogpgcheck http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm' was No package http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm available.

Comment: I also tried downloading the package and running your proposed command:

Comment: sudo yum install --nogpgcheck ./rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirrors.xmission.com
 * base: mirrors.easynews.com
 * extras: mirror.nic.uoregon.edu
 * rpmforge: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
 * updates: mirrors.easynews.com
Setting up Install Process
Examining ./rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm: rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386
./rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm: does not update installed package.
Nothing to d

Comment: It looks like you already installed the package. Perhaps the repo got disabled? Look for /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo and see if enabled=0. If so, change it to 1. If that file is missing entirely, remove and reinstall the package. Also, I fixed my install command in the original post